# Where do I ask Competitive coding questions which don't have solutions?

Tags: support, code

Where should one ask for hints and solutions regarding competitive coding problems/questions for which the author on some sites don't provide the answer, and I'm unable to solve the problem after spending a lot of time.

Comment: If it's fun enough, you might be able to try Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.

Comment: If you want to post on PPCG, you need to state the complexity requirement. Otherwise, you will get a bunch of brute force solution. StackOverflow was one possible venue, but I'm not sure about now - people don't like a question which is a dump of the problem statement. At the very least, you need to show some of your thinking and why the methods you considered didn't work.

Comment: Be sure to reveal where the question comes from and the date the competition closed (yes, past tense -- do not even try to post these questions while the competition is still running)